# Python assign variables in file

Tags: python, variables

I have a text file that says the following:

```
eggs,2.99
bacon,4.99
beer,5.96
raisins,3.81
oatmeal,4.13
lollipop,0.99
mints,1.13
```

Then I have the following code that asks which item they want
and if it's an item it prints work.

```
import os, time
f = open("Products.txt", "r")
def choose():
    itemlist = []
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(",")
        item = parts[0]
        price = parts[1]
        itemlist.append(parts[0])
        print '{:<15} {:>2}'.format(item, price)
    print("\nplease choose an item")
    print itemlist
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer in itemlist:
        print("WORK")

choose()
```

The program is meant to be like a cash register where you choose an item but I want for the price to be saved when an item is chosen. So if multiple items are set, it will add the price. I don't know how to find the price when they enter an item so I want to find a way to assign for instance "eggs" to its price.

Answer (score 1):

So good you know about data structures however for this it would be better to use a dictionary.

```
import os, time
f = open("Products.txt", "r")

def choose():
    items = {}
    for line in f:
        item, price = line.split(",")
        items[item] = parts[price]
        print '{:<15} {:>2}'.format(item, price)
    print("\nplease choose an item")
    print itemlist
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer in items.keys():
        print("WORK")

choose()
```

Now why is this better? Because you can easily reassign (ie `items["eggs"] = 1.05`)

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: To make it a bit more readable, unpack the item and price when you split the line ... ```item, price = line.split(","); items[item] = price```.  And ```if answer in items.keys()``` can/should be ```if answer in items```. Aaaannnnddd what is ```itemlist```?